# mampでapacheが起動しない

Tags: php, apache, mamp

macOS High Sierra
version 10.13.5

mampのstart serversをクリックすると、
MySQL ServerとCloudは起動しますが、
Apache Serverは起動せずに、`Apache couldn't be started. Please check your MAMP installation and configuration.` 
と表示されます。

しかし、ブラウザでlocalhostと入力すると`It works!`と表示されます。

起動していると思われるのにmampでは起動していないのは、どういった現象が起きていると考えられますか。

> Server version: Apache/2.4.33 (Unix)
>   Server built:   Apr  3 2018 18:00:56

```
ps aux | grep httpd
tanakaakio       55248   0.0  0.0  4267752    628 s000  R+    8:21PM   0:00.00 grep httpd

httpd -V
Server version: Apache/2.4.33 (Unix)
Server built:   Apr  3 2018 18:00:56
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:76
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Compiled using: APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
threaded:     no
forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
-D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
-D APR_HAS_MMAP
-D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
-D APR_USE_FLOCK_SERIALIZE
-D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
-D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
-D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
-D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
-D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
-D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr"
-D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/bin/suexec"
-D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/private/var/run/httpd.pid"
-D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
-D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
-D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/mime.types"
-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"
```

アパッチエラーログ

```
[Tue Jul 17 10:40:49 2018] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Jul 17 10:40:49 2018] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Jul 17 10:40:49 2018] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 10828)
[Tue Jul 17 10:40:49 2018] [notice] Apache/2.2.34 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.13 PHP/7.2.1 mod_ssl/2.2.34 OpenSSL/1.0.2j DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.24.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 17 13:29:51 2018] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test
[Tue Jul 17 13:42:30 2018] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test
[Tue Jul 17 13:48:06 2018] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jul 17 14:12:07 2018] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Jul 17 14:12:07 2018] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Jul 17 14:12:07 2018] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 1164)
[Tue Jul 17 14:12:07 2018] [notice] Apache/2.2.34 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.13 PHP/7.2.1 mod_ssl/2.2.34 OpenSSL/1.0.2j DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.24.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 17 14:13:39 2018] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jul 17 14:13:50 2018] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Jul 17 14:13:50 2018] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Jul 17 14:13:50 2018] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 1278)
[Tue Jul 17 14:13:50 2018] [notice] Apache/2.2.34 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.13 PHP/7.2.1 mod_ssl/2.2.34 OpenSSL/1.0.2j DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.24.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 17 14:20:25 2018] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject
[Tue Jul 17 14:21:01 2018] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject
[Tue Jul 17 14:48:12 2018] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject
[Tue Jul 17 14:52:12 2018] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject
[Tue Jul 17 14:54:20 2018] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject
[Tue Jul 17 15:03:33 2018] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject
[Tue Jul 17 15:24:08 2018] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject
[Tue Jul 17 15:25:12 2018] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/fuel
[Tue Jul 17 15:46:27 2018] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject
[Tue Jul 17 15:47:01 2018] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject
[Tue Jul 17 15:53:40 2018] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject
[Tue Jul 17 16:20:15 2018] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blog
[Tue Jul 17 16:23:03 2018] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject
[Tue Jul 17 16:45:59 2018] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/fuelphp
[Tue Jul 17 17:21:02 2018] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/fuel
```

他に必要な情報があれば提示します。
ご回答のほどよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 質問の際はなるべくアプリのバージョンや実行環境（OSの種類など）も記載するようにしましょう。質問の件については、MAMPで入れたApacheとは別に、OS本来のパッケージ管理で入れた別のApacheが既にインストールされている…などはないでしょうか。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/136864

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11193373426

Comment: 「起動していると思われる」の部分、`ps`コマンドの結果に表示されているのは確認のため実行した`grep httpd`の文字列に引っかかっているだけで、`httpd`のプロセスは確認できていないように見えます。

Comment: @cubick httpdのプロセスを確認して見ます

Comment: tanakaakionoiMac:~ tanakaakio$ ps aux | grep httpd
tanakaakio       13101   0.0  0.0  4276968    900 s000  S+   11:39AM   0:00.00 grep httpd だと一つのapacheだけが動いているって事ですよね？

Comment: その実行結果には`grep`コマンド自身のみがひっかかっており、`httpd`は起動していません。詳しくは https://webkaru.net/linux/ps-grep-exclude/ 辺りを参考にしてください。

Comment: grepコマンド自身のみが表示されてるだけって事が理解できました